# Elasticsearch 7.8.1: bulk add json error couldn't read data

Tags: json, elasticsearch, curl, bulk

I'm following this (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/getting-started-index.html) getting started: guide in order to bulk add documents in a json file that is in a amazon instance and when I run the json file (sample below) it returns an error (https://postimg.cc/yD74skSP) I'm completely new to Linux and developing by itself, do I'm yet trying to follow tutorials to getting best results.

```
{"index":{"_id":"333293"}}
{"group_id":"25","group_name":"COMPONENTES DE VEÍCULOS","class_id":"2520","class_name":"COMPONENTES DE TRANSMISSÃO DE VEÍCULOS","pdm_id":"14255","pdm_name":"ENGRENAGEM AUTOMOTIVA","catmat_id":"333293","catmat_name":"ENGRENAGEM AUTOMOTIVA, TIPO:DUPLA, APLICAÇÃO:TRATOR MF-265, ANO 1982","status":"Ativo","sustainable":"NÃO SUSTENTAVEL"}
{"index":{"_id":"350922"}}
{"group_id":"25","group_name":"COMPONENTES DE VEÍCULOS","class_id":"2520","class_name":"COMPONENTES DE TRANSMISSÃO DE VEÍCULOS","pdm_id":"14255","pdm_name":"ENGRENAGEM AUTOMOTIVA","catmat_id":"350922","catmat_name":"ENGRENAGEM AUTOMOTIVA, TIPO:ALTA VELOCIDADE DA CAIXA DE TRANSFERÊNCIA, APLICAÇÃO:VEÍCULO TOYOTA. 5 MARCHAS, MOTOR 14B, ANO 1995","status":"Ativo","sustainable":"NÃO SUSTENTAVEL"}
{"index":{"_id":"466192"}}
{"group_id":"25","group_name":"COMPONENTES DE VEÍCULOS","class_id":"2520","class_name":"COMPONENTES DE TRANSMISSÃO DE VEÍCULOS","pdm_id":"14255","pdm_name":"ENGRENAGEM AUTOMOTIVA","catmat_id":"466192","catmat_name":"ENGRENAGEM AUTOMOTIVA, TIPO:CAIXA TRANSMISSÃO 35 DENTES, APLICAÇÃO:VEÍCULO BLINDADO URUTU / CASCAVEL, REFERÊNCIA FABRICANTE:2342-000-757          ","status":"Ativo","sustainable":"NÃO SUSTENTAVEL"}
{"index":{"_id":"466193"}}
{"group_id":"25","group_name":"COMPONENTES DE VEÍCULOS","class_id":"2520","class_name":"COMPONENTES DE TRANSMISSÃO DE VEÍCULOS","pdm_id":"14255","pdm_name":"ENGRENAGEM AUTOMOTIVA","catmat_id":"466193","catmat_name":"ENGRENAGEM AUTOMOTIVA, TIPO:PLANETÁRIA, APLICAÇÃO:VEÍCULO BLINDADO URUTU / CASCAVEL, REFERÊNCIA FABRICANTE:2680-500-048","status":"Ativo","sustainable":"NÃO SUSTENTAVEL"}
{"index":{"_id":"466194"}}
{"group_id":"25","group_name":"COMPONENTES DE VEÍCULOS","class_id":"2520","class_name":"COMPONENTES DE TRANSMISSÃO DE VEÍCULOS","pdm_id":"14255","pdm_name":"ENGRENAGEM AUTOMOTIVA","catmat_id":"466194","catmat_name":"ENGRENAGEM AUTOMOTIVA, TIPO:SATÉLITE, APLICAÇÃO:VEÍCULO BLINDADO URUTU / CASCAVEL, REFERÊNCIA FABRICANTE:2680-500-056","status":"Ativo","sustainable":"NÃO SUSTENTAVEL"}
{"index":{"_id":"466195"}}
{"group_id":"25","group_name":"COMPONENTES DE VEÍCULOS","class_id":"2520","class_name":"COMPONENTES DE TRANSMISSÃO DE VEÍCULOS","pdm_id":"14255","pdm_name":"ENGRENAGEM AUTOMOTIVA","catmat_id":"466195","catmat_name":"ENGRENAGEM AUTOMOTIVA, TIPO:CAIXA DE DESCIDA 39 DENTES, APLICAÇÃO:VEÍCULO BLINDADO URUTU / CASCAVEL, REFERÊNCIA FABRICANTE:2342-000-196","status":"Ativo","sustainable":"NÃO SUSTENTAVEL"}
{"index":{"_id":"466197"}}
{"group_id":"25","group_name":"COMPONENTES DE VEÍCULOS","class_id":"2520","class_name":"COMPONENTES DE TRANSMISSÃO DE VEÍCULOS","pdm_id":"14255","pdm_name":"ENGRENAGEM AUTOMOTIVA","catmat_id":"466197","catmat_name":"ENGRENAGEM AUTOMOTIVA, TIPO:CAIXA DE DESCIDA 30 DENTES, APLICAÇÃO:VEÍCULO BLINDADO URUTU / CASCAVEL, REFERÊNCIA FABRICANTE:2342-000-129             ","status":"Ativo","sustainable":"NÃO SUSTENTAVEL"}
{"index":{"_id":"466873"}}
{"group_id":"25","group_name":"COMPONENTES DE VEÍCULOS","class_id":"2520","class_name":"COMPONENTES DE TRANSMISSÃO DE VEÍCULOS","pdm_id":"14255","pdm_name":"ENGRENAGEM AUTOMOTIVA","catmat_id":"466873","catmat_name":"ENGRENAGEM AUTOMOTIVA, TIPO:31 DENTES, APLICAÇÃO:VEÍCULO BLINDADO URUTU / CASCAVEL, REFERÊNCIA FABRICANTE:2342-000-153, USO:CAIXA DE TRANSMISSÃO MúLTIPLA","status":"Ativo","sustainable":"NÃO SUSTENTAVEL"}
{"index":{"_id":"466874"}}
{"group_id":"25","group_name":"COMPONENTES DE VEÍCULOS","class_id":"2520","class_name":"COMPONENTES DE TRANSMISSÃO DE VEÍCULOS","pdm_id":"14255","pdm_name":"ENGRENAGEM AUTOMOTIVA","catmat_id":"466874","catmat_name":"ENGRENAGEM AUTOMOTIVA, TIPO:35 DENTES, APLICAÇÃO:VEÍCULO BLINDADO URUTU / CASCAVEL, REFERÊNCIA FABRICANTE:2342-000-170, USO:CAIXA DE TRANSMISSÃO MúLTIPLA","status":"Ativo","sustainable":"NÃO SUSTENTAVEL"}
{"index":{"_id":"466875"}}
{"group_id":"25","group_name":"COMPONENTES DE VEÍCULOS","class_id":"2520","class_name":"COMPONENTES DE TRANSMISSÃO DE VEÍCULOS","pdm_id":"14255","pdm_name":"ENGRENAGEM AUTOMOTIVA","catmat_id":"466875","catmat_name":"ENGRENAGEM AUTOMOTIVA, TIPO:35 DENTES, APLICAÇÃO:VEÍCULO BLINDADO URUTU / CASCAVEL, REFERÊNCIA FABRICANTE:2342-000-340, USO:CAIXA DE TRANSMISSÃO MúLTIPLA","status":"Ativo","sustainable":"NÃO SUSTENTAVEL"}
{"index":{"_id":"466876"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's probably something wrong with the file path. Try `@/home/...` instead of `@home/...`

Also, make sure your file ends w/ a new line to prevent the `bulk request must be terminated by a newline [\\n]` error.

Comment: Flawless, do you know how to run this command in an amazon instance? Alredy run this command: https://postimg.cc/FkjHwsTw

Comment: I don't follow.